# python pip setup.py egg_info failed

Tags: python-3.x

when I pip install PyIxchariot, there are some errors as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line1, in<module>

File "C:\Python36-32\lib\codecs.py", line 321 in decode

  (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' code can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 81: invaild continuation byte

python setup.py egg_info failed
```

I don't know how to fix it...
And this is my first time for python pip install issue